# Facebook javascript JSON Error message

Tags: javascript, facebook

Im using [Cordova facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). And I copied from somewhere this code to post wall on my facebook and this error is saying `Post ID: "JSON Error"`. What I'm doing wrong?

```
var opts = {
    message : 'test',
        name : 'Post Title',
        link : 'www.postlink.com',
        description : 'post description'
    };

facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response);
    }
});
```

Comment: facebookConnectPlugin seems to be Apache Cordova's plugin for facebook.
Are you use the Facebook Javascript sdk, or a facebook plugin for cordova?

Comment: Using apache cordova.

Comment: any update on this question ?

Answer (score 1):

it might be the fact that the Cordova FB api is different from Facebook's sdk.

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#the-graph-api

It requires as the first parameter the url to call,
the second parameter is the permissions required,
third a success callback
and fourth an error callback.

Its not clear from the documentation how you should actually execute your request and how to add parameters to the request.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using this [Apache Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), but calling the functions based on the Facebook SDK documentation.

These are 2 separate SDKs. They have different functions, and they get different parameters.
This is how the `api` function is defined in the cordova plugin:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)
```

It expects different parameters then the one's what you're sending.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/

Comment: Can you provide example? I tried to add thoses params, only give me errors.